# Replace G24q-1 (4-pins) with a B22 Bayonet

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, cfl

Having recently moved house, I've noticed that the majority of the lighting upstairs is running CFLs using a type of connection that I am unfamiliar with (research says it's a G24q-1 cap but see photos below).

I'm looking to replace these with standard B22 Bayonet caps. However, since I'm unfamiliar with the G24q-1 cap I wanted to make sure that my approach is sound.

Here is the current configuration of what I believe to be a G24q-1
[image: current light fitting]

and a closeup of what I believe to be a G24q-1 cap that is currently fitted
[image: closeup of G24q-1 cap]

and here is the B22 Bayonet cap I have bought that I wish to fit
[image: standard B22 cap]

Now, my question is do I simply remove the existing base and fit the pendant in its place. Ensuring that all wires match up to where they are in the current arrangement (3/7 and 4/8) in the first picture?

Comment: Why B22 Bayonet ??  If it were me i would just buy new fixtures and led bulbs or just led fixtures.

Comment: The B22 Bayonet is the most common form of fixture in the UK. Which (although it does accept old incandescence) also provides the greatest choice for LED bulbs. I'm open to suggestions though, which LED fixture did you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ballast etc is inside the Eterna LEP13 lampholder and you can just change the lampholder or the pendant and leave the ceiling rose as it is.

This is a misguided attempt under Building Regs that require a certain proportion of lighting points in new build houses to be 'low energy'.

Similar product from MK

https://www.ebay.co.uk/c/1412633868

Answer (score 2):

### G24q-1 bulbs *do not take mains voltage*

I agree that the 8-terminal block is the standard UK mains splice. However, there must be a ballast or driver circuit between the mains connection and the G24q socket.

You must account for that before you can rewire.

My concern is that they may simply be using common UK wiring kit to extend from an external ballast to this location.  That would be reasonable to do if they use a ballast that can support 2+ lamps.

### This is an incandescent socket. Be careful!

A basic tenet of design is that fixtures not made for incandescents must not have sockets which could possibly take incandescents.

Even if you are enlightened enough to use efficient LEDs, the person who comes after you may slap in an incandescent.   At that point, the bulb is making **much more** heat than the fixture was ever designed to accommodate, and you can start a fire.

The bayonet socket you want to install will take incandescents.

I can't see the rest of the fixture,  but make sure it is listed and rated for incandescents.

If it is not, and  you want to fit LED bulbs, choose a socket type that only supports LEDs and not incandescents.  Or change to a fixture that is appropriate for incandescents.